# Redirect output to a directory

Tags: bash, shell

When attempting to redirect output to a directory I get the following error.

```
-bash: ua/: Is a directory
```

I know it's a directory. How do I redirect my output to it? Below is what I'm attempting. Thank you.

```
for file in .; do cut -d '"' -f 4 $file > ua/; done
```

Comment: are you attempting to redirect your output to a new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` redirection operator takes the output of a program and puts it in a *file*. Naturally, directories can't have "contents" the same way a file can, so this operator does not make sense for directories. That's why you get the error.

What I *think* you're trying to do is put the transformed contents of the file into a new file of the same name inside the directory. Again, the redirection operator has no notion of the source of its input - no idea that originally came from a file, let alone what that file is called. That being said, just redirect to a file of the same name inside the directory:

```
for file in ./*; do cut -d '"' -f 4 $file > ua/$file; done
```

**Edit:** The next problem you'll face is that your `for file in .` isn't doing what you expect. In fact this "loop" only ever loops once, with $file = ".". You probably want to utilise an expansion and do something like `for file in ./*.txt` to iterate all the text files for example.

Comment: Thank you. But the following still gives the same error.                          
 for file in .; do cut -d '"' -f 4 $file > ua/$file; done

Comment: @Sinkingpoint you did not copy well enough, you forgot the `$file` after `ua/`